# Laravel 5.2 and Mailgun - 500 Internal Server Error on Live Server

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-5, mailgun

i have my Mailgun driver working on Xampp. But when i try to send a email on my live server they throw a 500 internal server error.

> Here is my .env configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@mail.h****ine.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=4b6a*********7f6d21cf
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mail.har***e.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-4********8da6833510**0
```

> My controller

```
    \Mail::send('emails.template', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->from('postmaster@mail.ha*****e.com', 'My name');

        $message->to('fra***.xp@gmail.com')->subject('Message from...');
    });
```

> The error:

```
POST http://har***e.com/sendEmail 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what are the contents for the `$data` array?

Comment: have you add `guzzlehttp/guzzle` to composer.json and run `composer install` on your live server? what is the details on 500 error?

Comment: @h44f33z Hi, i have cPanel and i dont have console to do that. Only says 500 error. It's a ajax post problem.

Comment: Try execute the send email without ajax. You can use postman. One more thing, if you cannot run composer, you need to run on your local development then copy the whole vendor folder

Comment: @h44f33z Now i go to try that and tell you. Thanks.